Old anime where a cop puts an injured woman into a machine to revive her
I'm looking for a movie that starts off with the finding of a young woman, beaten and nearly dead. The cop puts her into machine to revive her against orders and so he fights an assassin in many scenes. The best part was when she goes to a casino and has a deep conversation with dealer as she wins it all on her second visit to the table. The chat is a cross of how to gamble and how to live, full of deep meanings, as she was the only player at the table.

What time is "early days"?

When did you watch this?
